# Get nearest Polyline to two points

Tags: android, google-maps

Given a list of polylines that are drawn on google maps, two points of latlong.
I want to get the nearest polyline to those two points.

one algorithm is to do it using only one point and get the nearest point to it on each polyline then calculate the nearest of those points on the polyline but it'd require too much processing.

so is any function in google maps api to do that ?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more, maybe adding a picture?

Comment: The statement _"nearest polyline to those two points"_ can mean at least two things: 1) it's nearest to either one of the points 2) it's nearest to the point exactly between those two points. And anyway, how to know which distance is the smallest one before calculating them? It requires processing whether the code already exists or you write it yourself.